# The jquery validating the form fields but not submitting the form data to targeted file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate the contact us form using jquery and ajax, the form fields are validating successfully ,but the data not submitted to php file i.e contact_submit.php.
please give me answer...... thank you !

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $(this);
        $('#frm').validate({
        rules: {
          name: {

            required: true
          },
          email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
          },
          mobile: {
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength:10,
            number:true,
            required: true
          },
          message: {
            required: true
          }
        },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('text-success').addClass('has-warning');
            },
            /*success: function(element) {
                element
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning').addClass('text-success');
            },*/
            submitHandler: function(form)
            {
                $ajax({
                    url: "contact_submit.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: $($form).serialize(),
                    success:function(response)
                    {
                        $('#msg').html('Your form is submited');
                    }

                });

            }
      });

});
```

I think there is mistake in my submithandler.

Comment: is this good??? '$($form)' ?

Comment: When debugging AJAX always have your browser's console open so that you can observe the request / response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you are using `var $form = $(this)` inside your document ready function and here **$(this)** refers to document not form and inside success handler function you using this `$($form).serialize()` ==> returns nothing.

**Changes :** removed `var $form =  $(this)` line and added `$("#frm").serialize();` in `submitHandler`.

Try this Code..

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#frm').validate({
            rules: {
              name: {

                required: true
              },
              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              },
              mobile: {
                minlength: 10,
                maxlength:10,
                number:true,
                required: true
              },
              message: {
                required: true
              }
            },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('text-success').addClass('has-warning');
                },
                /*success: function(element) {
                    element
                    .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-warning').addClass('text-success');
                },*/
                submitHandler: function(form)
                {
                    $ajax({
                        url: "contact_submit.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: $("#frm").serialize(), //Or $(form).serialize()
                        success:function(response)
                        {
                            $('#msg').html('Your form is submited');
                        }

                    });

                }
          });

    });
```

Comment: @user3736676, IMO, this should be the accepted answer, because it explains exactly how you went wrong with `$form = $(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is on the line `data: $($form).serialize()`
The dollar sign in front of `form` should not be there.

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you pointed out the root of this mistake.  The very first line:  `var $form = $(this);` and also explained how the `form` argument is already made available inside of the plugin's `submitHandler` callback.